# How to send notifications to specific register user through android app

Tags: android

I am developing a android app like GATEKEEPER , when a visitor came to apartment the operator take all details of flat owner and send a request notification to flat owner. The flat owner confirm or reject what ever it he is reply to that notification. After getting request conformation operator issue the visitor pass. I am checking the all tutorials in that everybody sending notifications to itself only please anybody knows the process explain me. Don't use firebase and any other web applications

Comment: Best way is using FCM . But if you don't want to then this can be done by `TEXT messaging` .

Comment: sorry i don't get that how can i use **text messaging** here